# Generate automatically variable and get values usign "document.getElementsByClassName"

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbytagname

I'm java script beginner, so do not be angry against me ;)

In order to simplify my code, I would like to generate automatically variables and affect them their current value in order to use them further.

What I have done and works (but I have a lot of changing variable on various documents) :

Html : input a,b,c,... with id a,b,c,...

```
a = Number($('#a').val());
b = Number($('#a').val());  
c = Number($('#c').val());
...
```

What I'm trying to do :

Html : add a class 'test' to all inputs I want to generate

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
elementsLength = elements.length;  
for (var i = 0 ; i < elementsLength ; i++) {
elements[i].value = Number($("#"+elements[i].id).val());
}
```

Something must be wrong in the part `elements[i].value = Number($("#"+elements[i].id).val());`

because when I call the variable a, b or c, it has not been generated.
after the loop,

```
alert (a);
```

returns `[object HTMLInputElement]` instead of the value I would like to get ;(

I'm searching since yesterday, I'm loose.
Thank you for your support guys.
++

Comment: The `value` property of an `<input>` element (or other form element like that) will always be a string. That assignment statement inside the `for` loop will not have any effect other than to possibly set the `value` to `NaN`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by creating references to the form values?

Comment: James, I have some input text and then when I execute the code by clicking a button, I check the validity of each input (ex #a value > 3). If the input do not success the validation test, I would like to write back the last validated value. To write the last validated values, I need before to "register" them after the last successful validity test. That's what I'm trying to do. Thank you for your support

Comment: Oh ok, then @Satpal has the right idea, you can create a variable (object) to hold the "valid" values and then insert them into the element's value if the validation fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want to persist the value of `INPUTS` in variable. I would suggest you to create an object i.e. `obj` and create properties based on input.

```js
var obj = {};
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.test').each(function() {
    obj[$(this).prop('id')] = Number($(this).val());
  });
  
  //For debugging
  console.clear();
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a" class="test">
<input type="text" id="b" class="test">
<input type="text" id="c" class="test">

<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Dear Satpal,
Thank you for your suggestion.
I'm working on it, but I did not yet found the way to adapt it on my code.
How can I then, ask the value of the input a, because alert(a); continue to answer me [object HTMLInputElement] Thank you

Comment: @Etienne use `obj.a`

Comment: Thank you, I'm really a noob...
Have a nice day ;)